# Python socket exploiting client address and port for response

Tags: python, sockets

(I have the following code in which I would like to implement a server-side application and to send clients a response:

```
class client(Thread):
  def __init__(self, socket, address):
     Thread.__init__(self)
     self.sock = socket
     self.addr = address
     self.start()

def run(self):
    request = ''
    while 1:
      data = self.sock.recv(1024).decode() # The program hangs here with large message
      if not data:
         break
      request += data
   print(request, self.addr[1], self.addr[0]))
   message = "test"
   self.sock.send(message.encode())


def init_server():
  serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  serversocket.bind((host, int(port)))
  serversocket.listen(5)
  while 1:
      clients, address = serversocket.accept()
      client(clients, address)
  return
```

Now I write a simple client:

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 8000))
client_socket.send(message)
request = ''
while 1:
  data = client_socket.recv(2048).decode()
  if not data:
  break
  request += data
print(request)
client_socket.close()
```

The problem now is that the server hangs in `recv` with a large message. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client socket and server socket are different sockets.

You can get server info using the `serversocket` object the same way you try `self.sock`.

I would recommend parsing `serversocket` as a third argument into your `client` class, and then using it within the class like so:

```py
class client(Thread):
  def __init__(self, socket, address, server):
     Thread.__init__(self)
     self.sock = socket
     self.addr = address
     self.server = server
     self.start()

def run(self):
    request=''
    while 1:
      data=self.sock.recv(1024).decode()
      if not data:
         break
      request+=data
   print(request, self.server.getsockname()[1], self.server.getsockname()[0]))

def init_server():
  serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  serversocket.bind((host, int(port)))
  serversocket.listen(5)
  while 1:
      clients, address = serversocket.accept()
      client(clients, address, serversocket)
  return
```

That should output the server information.

If you wanted the client information, it's parsed in the 'address' as a tuple, you can see the remote IP address and the socket port used to communicate on (not the open port).

Comment: I have modified the question to clarify the problem